# login to phpBB programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, phpbb

I am trying to log in to a phpBB forum. However, I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code.

```
import requests

forum = "https://adblockplus.org/forum/"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(forum + "ucp.php?mode=login", headers=headers, data=payload)
sidStart = r.text.find("sid")+4
sid = r.text[sidStart:sidStart+32]
parameters = {'mode': 'login', 'sid': sid}
r = session.post(forum, params=parameters)

if "Logout" in r.text:
    print("We are in")
else:
    print(r.text)

print(r)
```

It just always ends up not logged in.

Comment: I suggest instead of manipulating the website using `requests`, use a browser automation such as [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). This way you don't have to manage your own session and only have a few lines of code to craft each request. I have an example [here on GitHub](https://github.com/winny-/sirsi/blob/317928f23847f4fe85e2428598fbe44c4dae2352/sirsi/sirsi.py#L74-L211).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, mechanize is no longer developed ([last commit on Github is from February 2012](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize). Also, I would like to develop the app in Python3, which is not supported by the mechanize. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: I used `mechanize` as a familiar example, it looks like [`splinter`](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter) may be a good Python 3+ compatible and actively maintained choice. I urge you to reconsider, as your tool will be much less prone to breakage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import requests
forum = "https://adblockplus.org/forum/"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'redirect':'index.php', 'sid':'', 'login':'Login'}
session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(forum + "ucp.php?mode=login", headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Made some small changes like adding redirect, sid and login to payload and it seems to work. Not sure which one helped, I'll leave figuring that out up to you.

Comment: Have you ever been told you're awesome? It works like charm!

The problem was probably that I missed `'login':'Login'`. At least if I comment out this now, it doesn't work.

I'll upvote this as soon as I get the reputation.

Comment: @anon Haha, glad I could help :)

Comment: @anon By the way, I'd recommend downloading Fiddler it helps a ton when trying to inspect,recreate or even intercept and resend http requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only Linux. Thanks for the suggestion anyway, because there are [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/fiddler/)

Comment: good day MadRabbit and anon: thanks for the thread and for the answer too. Great to see that you use  the payload-solution: This is great. Many thanks = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'redirect':'index.php', 'sid':'', 'login':'Login'}
session = requests.Session()